# is <a> tag post method or get method?

Tags: post, get, atag

I was working on a Spring Security logout with React.js and used the  tag to send a /logout request cause axios didn't seem to work with the post method. isn't it supposed to be a post method to access the logout() method with the default "/logout" request? the  tag seems to be working like the post method but I wasn't sure.

So, my question is, is the  tag get method, post method or none of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get.
Opening a url is a get method, i think the same apply for a redirect.